# Stop a program from running when I plug in my iPhone

Tags: windows

Whenever I plug in my iPhone into my work computer Word 2007 decides it wants to start up.

How do I make it stop? Is it a registry deal, or is there an Windows interface that I'm unaware of. I'm on Win XP SP3 by the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check your autorun settings.

iPhones show as camera devices; it's possible that you have Word associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

Go into Windows Explorer, find your iphone under the "My Computer" folder, right click it and select "Properties", then go to the "Events" tab and click "Do nothing" or select what you want to do when you connect your iPhone.

Comment: I dont have an event tab. I can take a screenshot if need be. This is driving me nuts. All I have is a General Tab. I don't have the color management tab either - From [arlen-top](http://superuser.com/users/221922/arlen-torp)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to change the AutoRun/AutoPlay settings.

Microsoft has more information on doing this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Change-AutoPlay-settings

For Windows XP, you have to look somewhere else: [http://www.winbookcorp.com/_technote/WBTA20000846.htm]

Comment: He's using Windows XP.

Comment: Updated to include WinXP.

Answer (score 1):

Control Panel > Scanners and Cameras > iPhone (right click) property.

[image]

Comment: Apparently you did not hide all of your private information